# What show was this? Early '90s-ish, computerized nudity filters stop the VR/simulation before a character in a pool can take off her top

Tags: story-identification, tv

I thought it was the show *Sliders*, but I can't find evidence of this scenario in the show. I sure remember a *Sliders* vibe to the look and feel of the show but of course it's been a long time since then. It must have been early/mid 1990s when I saw it. I suppose the show could have been a little bit older rerun. It would have been at home on broadcase TV (since we didn't have cable until I was older) in the Front Range region of Colorado.

All I remember is the main character is with a woman (maybe on an innertube) in a bikini. She goes to take her top off but the computer filters won't allow it and forces him instead to exit the simulation.

Would love to 1st of all to find the show because it kick-started my interest in VR at an early age, but also would like to use the clip in a VR history demo thing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was it the 1990s when you saw it, or is that a guess based on the appearance of the show?  Where did you see it?

Comment: Thanks! Yep it must have been early/mid 1990s when I saw it. I suppose the show could have been a little bit older rerun. I sure remember a Sliders vibe to the look and feel of the show but of course it's been a long time since then.

Comment: Oh sorry - where did I see it: would have been at home on network TV, we didn't have cable until I was older. Front range Colorado TV stations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This occurs in *[Island City](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(1994_film))* from 1994. It's not the main character but rather the teenage son of a character - thus the V-chip.

From the wiki page:

> The film features virtual reality goggles. The son of the missing
> soldier uses the goggles to study and do his history homework, and
> also to spend time fishing with his father. He also attempts to
> fulfill his sexual fantasies, but a parental block prevents his
> fantasy girl from removing her top.

Here's the whole movie on YouTube

Go to 1:02:00 for the scene you remember.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed it! Didn't remember it playing out just like that but that is definitely the right scene. Well done sir, and thank you!